# Word and Text relation using python and NLP

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, classification, nltk

I have a word, according to that i want to find out whether the text is related to that word or not using **python and nltk** is it possible ?

For example I have a word called "**phosphorous**". I would like to find out that the particular text file is **related to this word or not**?

I cant use bag of words in nltk as I have only one word and no training data.

Any Suggestions?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not without a corpus, no.

Look at it this way: can you, an intelligent being, tell whether 光 is related to 部屋に入った時電気をつけました without asking someone or something that actually knows Japanese (assuming you don't know Japanese; if you do, try with "svjetlo" and "Kad je ušao u sobu, upalio je lampu"). If you can't, how do you expect a computer to do it?

And another experiment - can you, an intelligent being, give me the algorithm by which you can teach a non-english-speaking person that "light" is related to "When he entered the room, he turned on the lamp"? Again, no.

tl;dr: You need training data, unless you significantly restrict the meaning of "related" (to "contains", for example).

Comment: This! The human brain does nothing else than match something against the data it already has to find patterns or irregularities in order to identify or understand the thing. In Amadans example, I can only guess 'upalio je lampu' to have something to do with a 'lamp" because I recognize 'lamp' (pattern) in it and have learnt what a lamp (training data) is. Now I love lamp even more.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the nltk wordnet to calculate path similarity score between the word and words in your other text and estimate a heuristics based on that score:

`from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
    hit = wn.synset('hit.v.01')
    slap = wn.synset('slap.v.01')
    wn.path_similarity(hit, slap)`

You can find more nltk word-net usage examples here:
http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html

Comment: this would require some experimentation and tweaking of the heuristics, but if you have nothing, it may be worth a try!